# Replacing a string in a Table with another string

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to solve a problem using the `sed` command. 
I have a Table with data (few rows and cols). 
I want to be able to replace the string in the `i,j` spot with a new string. 
For an example :

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word5 word6 word7 word8
word9 word10 word11 word12
```

with the input of `1,1` and `abc` should return

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word5 abc word7 word8
word9 word10 word11 word12
```

And if possible, print it to a new file. 
Thanks

Comment: Does it really have to be with `sed`?

Comment: In addition to what @JohnZwinck mentioned, also add a correct example.  Your example output with input of `1,1` and `abc` doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: @devnull Yes it does - he's counting from zero.

Comment: @AdamSpiers It _somehow_ seemed to me that it was indexed from 0 in one direction and from 1 in other.

Comment: Yes, I'm counting from 0,0..

Answer (score 5):

Using awk might be easier:

```
awk -v c=1 -v r=1 -v w='abc' 'NR==r+1{$(c+1)=w}1' file
word1 word2 word3 word4
word5 abc word7 word8
word9 word10 word11 word12
```

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest too.  `sed` is a stream editor, not a record editor.

Comment: Hey,we are not allowed to use the awk command.
Im not really familiar with the sed command, thats why I asked here.
If you have other suggestions, I would appericiate them

Comment: Its for our homework.. :\ They specified what we should and shouldnt use.

Comment: Well good luck with sed (not impossible but will be fairly complicated in sed)

Comment: So basically you want someone to do your homework for you. You won't learn anything that way. Why don't you try a few things first and then ask when you get stuck?

Comment: Well, Basically this is 0.001$ of the assignment which I got stuck on and searched for a good solution instead of wasting too much time. No need to be an a$$.